# remove specific lines and one symbol out of txt file

Tags: vbscript

Hey guys i have written a little vbs to open a txt file and remove some lines and `\` in each line. Everything works correctly but the last line of my source file is written multiple times to the destination file. Its only the last line all other lines are written once. So what is wrong with my code? This is what i do:

```
Option Explicit
Dim strLine 
Dim strNewLine 
Dim strRawPath
Dim strRawPathW
Dim WshShell
Dim f
Dim w
Dim fs
Dim fsw
Dim x


x = 0

strRawPath = "C:\xampp_neu\xampp\htdocs\tc_backup\stasknoheader.txt"
strRawPathW = "C:\xampp_neu\xampp\htdocs\tc_backup\stask.txt"

Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fsw = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        ' 2 = ForWriting
        Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(strRawPath,1)
        Set w = fsw.OpenTextFile(strRawPathW,2)

            Do While f.AtEndOfStream <> True
                x = x+1
                ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
                strLine = f.Readline
                myArray(x) = strLine

                 If InStr(strLine, "Microsoft") = 0 Then
                    If InStr(strLine, "TaskName") = 0 Then
                        If InStr(strLine, "Restart System") = 0 Then
                            IfInStr(strLine,"SchedulerHSMmigTC11TDrive") = 0 Then


                        strNewLine = strLine
                        strNewLine =(Replace(strLine,"\","",1,1))
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If                  

                w.write strNewLine & VbCrLf

            Loop 

        f.Close
        w.Close
```

Comment: Before first `If InStr(..` write `strNewLine = strLine`

Comment: @VMV this doesn't help it destroys more zhan it helps

Comment: Then please explain which line should be removed and which processed?

Comment: @VMV Lines which contain `Microsoft` or `TaskName` or `Restart System` or `SchedulerHSMmigTC11TDrive` should be removed and all other lines there should remove the character "\"

Comment: Then simple put `w.write strNewLine & VbCrLf` inside `IF` statetment, after `strNewLine =(Replace(strLine,"\","",1,1))` string.

Comment: @VMV that was the solution thanks! Can you write it as answer so i can mark it as wright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just move `w.write strNewLine & VbCrLf` inside `IF` statetment, after `strNewLine =(Replace(strLine,"\","",1,1))` string.